# NVD3.js (d3.js) Scale Break

Tags: d3.js, scale, nvd3.js

I want to create a chart with scale break on y axis. I don't want to use a non-linear scale but using a scale break make lower values more visible when having data anomalies. 
What is the best way to implement that in nvd3 or in general in d3?

Comment: You can't do this in NVD3 without modifying the source code. In D3, I would go with different scales for different input ranges.

Comment: Thanks Lars, I want to do that but do not know what is the best approach. Should I create a new Scale, something like linears_with_break scale? I am trying to make sense of the d3 code but quite don't know how to do it...

Comment: [This tutorial](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/using-multiple-axes-for-d3js-graph.html) isn't quite what you're looking for, but it should give you an idea how to start.

Comment: I am looking for this too. I'm surprised it doesn't seem to be built into D3, considering the vastness otherwise of the library.

Answer (score 3):

Lacking other options I created a brute force solution, manipulating the vertical `<path>` of the Y axis.

Using pseudo code, you use it like this:

```
var domainPath = yAxis
    .select('path.domain');

domainPath.attr('d', breakScale(domainPath.attr('d'), 14, 6, 4, 7);
```

The breakScale function is not very special nor elegant, but here it goes:

```
function breakScale(pathString, amplitude, wavelength, periods, dist){
    var parts = pathString.match(/(.*)(H-\d+)/);
    var first = parts[1];
    var last = parts[2];
    first = first.replace(/(.*?V)(\d+)/, function(match, p1, p2) { return p1 + (p2-dist-(wavelength)*periods) });

    var newPath = first;

    for(var i=0; i<periods+1; i++){
        if(i === 0){
            newPath += 'l-' + (amplitude/2) + ',' + (wavelength/2);
        }
        else if(i == periods){
            newPath += 'l' + (i%2?'':'-') + (amplitude/2) + ',' + (wavelength/2);        
        }
        else {
            newPath += 'l' + (i%2?'':'-') + amplitude + ',' + wavelength;
        }
    }

    newPath += 'v' + dist + last;

    return newPath;
}
```

`dist` defines the distance from the start of the axis that the wavy thing should begin. The function probably works best with even numbers for `amplitude` and `wavelength` because they are both halved for the first and last part of the wave. `periods`should be at least 3.

Given a typical domain axis path string like `M-6,0H0V376H-6`, it will spit back something like `M-6,0H0V345l-7,3l14,6l-14,6l14,6l-7,3v7H-6` which would look like this:

[image]