# How to introduce a break in charts using d3js/nvd3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

I have been using d3/nvd3 for over 2 weeks now and have been playing around with it. I recently made a scatter chart

```
nv.addGraph(function () {
var chart = nv.models.scatterChart()
    .showDistX(true) //showDist, when true, will display those little distribution lines on the axis.
.showDistY(true)
    .transitionDuration(350)
    .color(d3.scale.category10().range());

//Configure how the tooltip looks.
chart.tooltipContent(function (key) {
    return '<h3>' + key + '</h3>';
});

//Axis settings
chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function (d) {
    return d;
});
chart.yAxis.tickFormat(function (d) {
    return getCategoryForIndex(d);
});

chart.forceX(0);
chart.xAxis.tickValues([0,12,15,17,18,19,21]);

//We want to show shapes other than circles.
chart.scatter.onlyCircles(true);

var myData = processData(data);
d3.select('#chart svg')
    .datum(myData)
    .call(chart);

nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

return chart;
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/eyedagger/JRnqf/

The data starts rendering from tick 12 at x-axis. What I really couldn't figure out was, how could I break the x-axis so the chart would have bubbles scattered evenly. Please put me in a right direction.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249054/nvd3-js-d3-js-scale-break) may help.

Comment: If I may, the solution doesn't really break the axis as you can see that the start for y is 40. Also the steps are the same (5). Even if I used it, it wouldn't shrink the part of the axis where it does not have any data.

Comment: I am more interested in a functional solution than a pictorial solution. It would also work for me if there were no signs as such but the empty area on the x-axis could be shrunk somehow.

Comment: Comment these two lines `chart.forceX(0);` & `chart.xAxis.tickValues([0,12,15,17,18,19,21]);` and the bubbles will be evenly distributed. And it would shrink the path of the aix where it does not have any data.